# Error: setting variant to selection - one or more cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, which is called when a monitored worksheet is changed:

```
Public Sub selectionCallback(tag As String, ByVal target As Range)
    Set cellAddress = target
    Set cellValue = Nothing
    cellValue = target.Value
End Sub
```

When i try to retrieve `cellValue(1, 1)` i get no problem - unless i only selected one cell - then i get a type mismatch.

I am using these values to compare newly entered data, and thereby tracking changes to be sent by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are using a variant and Excel is guessing what type of value cellValue should be. When you send it a values of multiple cells in a range it becomes a 2 dimensional array, when you send it a single value it treats it like a double.

A a double it doesn't have an indexed value. A simple workaround would be to use the following code, but it isn't a best practice and it would be better to test whether cell value was an array in a seperate function.

```
Public Sub selectionCallback(tag As String, ByVal target As Range)

    Dim cellAddress As Range
    Dim cellValue As Variant

    Set cellAddress = target
    cellValue = target.Value

    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox CStr(cellValue(1, 1))
    MsgBox cellValue
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```